# What is the ideal maxActive value for tomcat datasource for a high concurrency application?

Tags: sql-server, tomcat, connection-pooling

What is the ideal maxActive value for tomcat datasource for a high concurrency application?
Especially in the production environment. My application's DB is SQL Server.

When sending multiple requests I currently see the below error:

```
java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.springframework.jdbc.CannotGetJdbcConnectionException: Could not get JDBC Connection; nested exception is org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp.SQLNestedException: Cannot get a connection, pool error Timeout waiting for idle object
```

Setting maxActive to -1 resolves my problem, but is that an ideal value for a production environment?

Comment: I have it currently set to 400 based on my application.

Answer (score 1):

I guess, you really have to benchmark.

We load-tested our Tomcat and were surprised that throughput peeked at around a max. of 10 concurrent connections, when we initially thought the value of `maxActive` should be much higher. (Disclaimer: This is an inhouse app, where the DB is running on a relatively small box. The correct value might be considerably higher if you're running a high concurrency app on a power horse).

There's good background information about pool sizing on HikariCP's wiki pages, which should also apply to Apache DBCP shipped with Tomcat:

https://github.com/brettwooldridge/HikariCP/wiki/About-Pool-Sizing

It basically says you should set the number of concurrent connections to twice the number of CPU cores available to your DB instance. But again, I would load-test your app to confirm that number.

After you have found the optimal pool size, rather consider increasing the `maxWait` property of the pool to avoid the `CannotGetJdbcConnectionException` exception you are mentioning. See the DBCP's JavaDoc for details:

http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-dbcp/api-1.4/org/apache/commons/dbcp/BasicDataSource.html#maxWait